# Azure Devops Server Password variable parameter to powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am passing a password in Azure Devops Server Variable to a powershell method. When the variable is marked as a ** in AD then the code does not work. But if I just pass the variable as plain string it works.

```
$password =  ConvertTo-SecureString -String $passwordParam -AsPlainText -Force

$Credentials= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ( $user, $password )

Send-MailMessage -From $emailAddressFrom -To $SendTo -Subject  'Test Message' -Body $body-SmtpServer $server -port $port -UseSsl -Credential $Credentials
```

Comment: What is `passwordParam`?

Comment: It's probably $passwordParam = "hunter2"

Comment: thats the variable thats passed in from my azure devops variable which uses **** to mask it